# RStudio and Lazy Evaluation

Tags: r, rstudio, lazy-evaluation

I am mainting the package "hdm" and I encountered the following problem.
The following code runs in plain R and used to run in RStudio, but not anymore:

```
library(hdm)
attach(GrowthData)
fmla=  "Outcome ~ ."
fmla.y= "Outcome ~ . - gdpsh465 "
rY= rlasso(fmla.y, data =GrowthData)
```

Error message:

> Error in exists("homoscedastic", where = penalty) : object 'n' not
>   found

If no penalty in the function rlasso is specified it is set by default containing the variable "n", the sample size of x, which is evaluated later.
n is gotten by lazy evaluation and it seems that in RStudio the correct environment is not found anymore.

The error occurs here, but the problem is that penalty contains n which is not know

```
if (!exists("homoscedastic", where = penalty))  penalty$homoscedastic = "FALSE"
```

Somehow I am not sure to solve this and would like to ask if you have any idea.

Thanks a lot for your efforts in advance!

Best,

Martin

Comment: I get the same error in R as well, so it's not (just) an RStudio problem.

Comment: Under following R configuration it works:

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] hdm_0.2.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] backports_1.0.3 tools_3.3.1     checkmate_1.8.1 Formula_1.2-1

Comment: It is really strange. It worked before, but recently the error shows up. R does lazy evaluation and at time of evaluation n is here not known any more. I think the problem is much before. Maybe somehow an evaluation of the penalty can be forced earlier. I am not sure.

Comment: `rlasso(Outcome ~ . - gdpsh465, data = GrowthData)` works, but not `rlasso("Outcome ~ . - gdpsh465", data = GrowthData)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `x` is a character object, the problem arises because `n` is not defined in the environment from which `rlasso.formula` is called, i.e. `rlasso.character()`, or its parents. This is roughly what's happening:

```
test <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("test")
}
test.character <- function(x, pen = list(alpha = n)) {
  test.formula(x, pen = pen)
}
test.formula <- function(x, pen = list(alpha = n)) {
  n <- 2
  test.default(x, pen)
}
test.default <- function(x, pen = list(alpha = n)) {
  n <- 3
  exists("alpha", where = pen)
}

test("y ~ x")
# Error in exists("alpha", where = pen) : object 'n' not found
test(y ~ x)
# [1] TRUE
test(123)
# [1] TRUE
```

A workaround is to not specify `pen` in the call to the `formula` method if it's not defined when the `character` method is called:

```
test.character <- function(x, pen = list(alpha = n)) {
    if (missing(pen))
      test.formula(x)
    else
      test.formula(x, pen = pen)
}
test("y ~ x")
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to solve the problem (although I am still puzzled as in plain R it works and only in RStudio the error occured.) Any thoughts on this sill welcom.

Comment: It didn't work for me in plain R, either in v3.4.3 or in v3.3.1. I don't think it's an RStudio problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! I am still puzzled.